# Enhancing my code that calculates Slope Sign Change (SSC)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am trying to code this Slope Sign Change (SSC) formula:

[image]

My attempt below seems to be missing something since it generates `-2` instead of `1`. I am really stuck in this.

```
signal = np.sin(np.linspace(1, 10)) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(np.linspace(1, 10)))
ssc = np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(signal)))
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can compute the temporal difference with [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) as you did:

  - `x_{n} - x_{n-1}` with `np.diff(x, prepend=1)[1:-1]`

    or with slicing: `x[1:-1] - x[:-2]`.
  - `x_{n} - x_{n+1}` with `-np.diff(x)[1:]`

    or with slicing: `x[1:-1] - x[2:]`
- You can implement `f` with a mask given a threshold `delta`:

  ```
  f = lambda x: (x >= delta).astype(float)
  ```

The resulting expression for `SSC` is:

```
SSC = sum(f(-np.diff(x, prepend=1)[1:-1]*np.diff(x)[1:]))
```

Comment: Clean. Thank you very much